# ExtJS: How to call a function within another function?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store, getter-setter

I know there are a bunch of questions about **calling a function in another function** but unfortunately none of them worked for me or I couldn't implement to my project!

I've a `Window` class and two functions have been stated inside. The second one is getting getting a specific URL with ID through a `combobox` and returning it. I need to use this generated `URL` in the first `function`;

```
getSelectCountry: function(){
        var countryRecord   = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=country]')[0].getSelectedRecord();
        var countryId       = countryRecord.get('id');
        var urlWithId       = MyApp.Globals.getUrl() + '/city/view/list/?countryid='+ countryId;

        // var store =  Ext.getStore('cityCombo');
        // store.load({
        //     url : MyApp.Globals.getUrl() + '/city/view/list/?countryid='+ countryId,
        // });

        return urlWithId;
    }
```

and I need to use this returned `urlWithId` below in `citycombo`, within `proxy`'s `url`. It'll list cities depends on country that below;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.weather.SettingsWindow', { 
...
getSettingsItems: function () {
        var me = this;

        var settingsItems = [
           {
                xtype: 'form',
                layout: {type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch', pack: 'start'},
                reference: 'settingsForm',
                items: [
{
                        xtype: 'citycombo',
                        itemId: 'cityName',
                        name: 'city',
                        afterLabelTextTpl: MyApp.Globals.required,
                        allowBlank: false,
                        flex: 1,
                        store: {
                            storeId: 'cityCombo',
                            proxy: {
                                type: 'ajax',
                                // I neeed returned URL with ID on here.
                                url: MyApp.Globals.getUrl() + '/city/view/list/', 
                                reader: {
                                    type: 'json',
                                    rootProperty: 'data'
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 0,
                            sorters: 'description',
                            autoLoad: true
                        }
                    },
```

I've tried use `store.load` or create a new variable and calling it but I couldn't be success for any of tries.

I'll be pleasure for any idea.

---

**UPDATE**

- Please check those screen-shot: [UI](https://prnt.sc/i5da7f) and [code structure](https://prnt.sc/i5dbnl)
- I'm trying to get this full `URL` generated by `getSelectCountry` function **(1)** and filter cities query on `citycombo` with this new returned URL **(2)**.

Comment: What is the result when you do console.log(countryId) ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to dynamically determine the URL for every load operation by calling the getSelectCountry function, is this correct?

Comment: @JorgeMejia It's giving `integer` id of which I need; such as *87* and when console `urlWithId` generates exact URL which I need on **citycombo** such as: *http://URL/city/view/list/?countryid=97*

Comment: @Alexander I need to take this param such as `?countryid=97` from `countrycombo` and pass it to end of `citycombo`'s url such as *URL/city/view/list/?countryid=97*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

1. Extend *Alexander's* solution. Assuming the `cityCombo` has the beforeload callback defined setting the `url` or `extraparams`, You  define a `change` listener on the `country` combobox, and calling `cityCombo's` `load()` from there.

See below:

```
listeners: {
    change: function () {
        Ext.getStore('cityCombo')
            .load()
    }
}
```

Or even better, remove the `beforeload` from the store and put what's there in the `change` of the first `combobox`

```
listeners: {
    change: function (combo, newValue) {
        var cityStore = Ext.getStore('cityCombo')
        cityStore.getProxy()
            .setUrl(getSelectedCountry());

        cityStore.load();
    }
}
```

Note: you could refactor it even further, getting rid of the `getSelectedCountry()` and doing all of it on the combo passed by the listener

2. Use filter on the `cityCombo` instead of the round trip

Edit: Fixed display of the first code block, addd missing `load()` call.

Comment: OK! Probably I got that! I've configured code such this one below in country combo listener and it loads exact URL i need for query. But it's not load this URL to citycombo's proxy url. Still displays cities that have diffferent countryid.

Comment: Code: `change: function (combo, countryId) {
                                debugger;
                                Ext.getStore('cityCombo')
                                    .getProxy()
                                    // .setUrl(this.getSelectCountry())
                                    .setUrl(MyApp.Globals.getUrl() + '/city/view/list/?countryid='+ countryId)
                            }`

Comment: Should I configure the `citybombo` as well? Such as a `listener` waits for country combo?

Comment: @NuriEngin: My bad. I forgot to add the final load to the chain after the `setUrl()` (so you can avoid the extra listener on the `cityCombo`). Editing the answer.

Comment: That's weird but it says: `TypeError: Ext.getStore(...).getProxy(...).setUrl(...).load is not a function` :|

Comment: I hope I'm doing right: I've listen your advice and rid of the `getSelectCountry` func. Then configured your `change` sample on `countrycombo` as this:                                 **Ext.getStore('cityCombo').getProxy().setUrl(MyApp.Globals.gettUrl() + '/city/view/list/?countryid='+ countryId).load();**. It generates exact URL with country ID but still can not load this new URL to `citycombo`. The error is on the comment above.

Comment: When I checked Network tab, it is doing request for list of both city & country from DB when I open the `window` but still could be the error related with this post: Trying loading still when it doesn't exict @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008416/7163711

Comment: oh, right. another correction. as it is right now we're calling `load()` on the proxy, when it should be on the store. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: It works! During `countrycombo` selection gives no error and fetching the exact request from DB, fetching *city/list?countryid*. So far everything ok **but** somehow it's not load to this specified `url` to `citycombo` selection!? Still displays all the cities around world. Not filter by that URL parameter!? :( :|

Comment: actually that seems server-side error. Let me examine it!

Comment: Unfortunately I've missed an important thing! During REST request searching url is changing to this; `'city/view/search?query=countryid:'+ countryId`. So When I use `change` event on country combo it gives error 404 not found which is a very normal behaviour. I've checked `combobox` `events` on Sencha docs but there are not any event like *afterload* or etc. Tried to use normal `select` event and it works during country selection but do not loads this new searching URL above. As well `afterrender` event is giving 404 error. =(

Comment: Dear @Mieszko your sample worked **wonderful**!! Thanks a lot. Well I forgot to added `/` character in query url that was the reason of error!

Comment: Just getting another stupid error; when I start to typing *country name* to `combobox` field, it's fire `/city/view/search?query=countryid:...` through listener. And of course gives error because `countryid` is empty yet! And when I change the listener event from `change` to `select`, it's not giving error because I did not click/enter on country but also somehow it's add `id` end of search query url! So I'm looking for a solution to tell app: hey not to do searching while I'm typing.

Answer (score 1):

If it's all about that tiny parameter, what you really want to do is populate the `extraParams` property in the beforeload listener of the store.

```
listeners: {
    beforeload: function(store) {
        // Get countryRecord from somewhere...
        store.getProxy().setExtraParams("countryid", countryRecord.get('id'))
    }
```

If the server/pathname is also different, you can also `setUrl()`.

Relevant fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2c8a

UPDATE:

So, what you really want to do:

```
    xtype: 'combobox',
    queryMode: 'local',
    fieldLabel: 'Country',
    store: ...,
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, countryRecord) {
            var cityStore = combo.nextSibling().getStore();
            cityStore.getProxy().setExtraParam('countryId', countryRecord.get('Id'));
            cityStore.load();
        }
    },
},{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    queryMode: 'local',
    fieldLabel: 'City',
    store: ...,
```

Comment: Dear @Alexander, I'm try to do this; As you will see on screenshot below, I've a `window` three combo included. The first combo is for **country** and the second one is for **city**. When I choose country, it will take it's `countryid` and when clicks on city combo, will generate a new query with `countryid` on city-combo such as *URL + city/list/countryid* to display cities that belong choosed country. 

**ScreenShot**: https://prnt.sc/i4s621

Comment: I'm not sure if your example work on this configuration but I'll try to implement it.

Comment: I've defined listener under `citycombo` and added **debugger** just inside the `beforeload` but it seems that it doesn't fire the function. `listeners: {beforeload: function (store) {debugger; store.getProxy().setUrl(getSelectCountry);`